# Trigonometric Fourier series of absolute cosine

Tags: fourier-series

I am having trouble finding the trigonometric Fourier series of

$|cos(\pi*t/2)|$ where $1\leq t<3$.

I understand that since its an even function all $b_n$ will be zero. The limit is throwing me off. Please guide me on how to approach this problem. Thanks

Comment: You mean a part of a periodic even cosine function?  An odd function has no$~a_n$ and an  even function has no $~b_n$ coefficients.

Comment: Correct and the function I defined above is even so b_n=0